# Does intellij CE support .jsp?

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea

I'm following a tutorial in the net and i cant seem to produce the supposed output, and whenever i go to my .jsp file, there's a pop up on the top area saying "try IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate".

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA Community edition doesn't support JSPs and app servers.

You can find more details in the [editions comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Comment: I don't see "JSP" in that matrix, but maybe it's in "Java EE"? Any idea or links to what the JSP support looks like? Does it allow you to control-click navigate, or refactor?

Comment: @dfrankow Yes, JSP navigation and refactorings are supported. You can get a trial version and use it for 30 days to see yourself what's supported.